# How to open complex number file in python that generated by C program?

Tags: python-3.x, complex-numbers

My code

```
with open('car.FT','r', encoding="utf-8",errors='ignore') as h:
    for line in h:
        print(line)
```

File "car.FT" is output of Fourier transform that has complex values stored.It is written through a C program but I want to open this file in python.
The output is not readable with this above piece of code used.
The file is written in C :

```
typedef struct complex {    /* Define a complex type */
    float r,i;          /* Real and imaginery parts */
    } COMPLEX;

/* buffer for input image being converted into complex type */
COMPLEX IN_BUF[ROWS][COLS];

///PROCESSING ON IN_BUF////

fwrite(IN_BUF, sizeof(COMPLEX), ROWS*COLS, fout);
```

Here below is the data actually in the file. That I want to read.

[image]

I want to read this above file data in python.

Comment: What's the expected result?  How was the file written in C?  Also don't post images of text.  Are we supposed to manually type it in to try it out?  Use cut-and-paste of the actual text.

Comment: text in the image is the output I want. In C program I created a buffer and write file with fourier transform data that is complex number in the file "car.FT"

Comment: @JoeFerndz Sorry this totally different from what I am looking for.

Comment: i have never read image file the way you have written. I try to do it this way... https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/working-images-python/?ref=rp

Comment: @CrisLuengo I have attached the code and the data actually in the file. I want to read that in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the C code the numbers are written as binary float numbers, and what you are showing is the hex output of the file contents. In this case, you have to read the *binary* contents, while you are trying to read it as a text file.

You have to open the file in binary mode (`rb`), read and convert each float value (which is 4 bytes long) using `struct.unpack`, and convert pairs of float to `complex`. Here is a simple implementation (untested):

```py
from struct import unpack

numbers = [] 
with open(filename, "rb") as f:
    data = f.read()  # read all data
count = len(data) // 8  # each complex number takes 8 bytes
i = 0
for index in range(count):
    # "f" means float (4 bytes); unpack returns a tuple with one value
    real = unpack("f", data[i:i + 4])[0]
    i += 4
    im = unpack("f", data[i:i + 4])[0]
    i += 4
    numbers.append(complex(real, im))

print(numbers)
```

Comment: here count will become float and we cannot assign float in range.

Comment: Ah ok, corrected the answer (should use int division)

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "new.py", line 10, in <module>
    numbers.append(complex(real, im))
TypeError: complex() first argument must be a string or a number, not 'tuple'

Comment: Sorry, now forgot that `unpack` always returns a tuple. I changed it a bit more, should now work (I should have tested the code before...)